# При маштабировании некоректно отображается анимация?

Tags: css

При маштабировании некоректно отображается анимация белого овала, сползает вниз на текст или наоборот не доходит до конца линии. Подскажите что делаю не так? Спасибо

https://jsfiddle.net/koeyqasf/41/

```css
.main-block__scroll {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #161616;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.main-block__image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 24px;
  width: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  z-index: 2;
  animation: line 4s linear infinite alternate;
}

.main-block__line {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid #3e3e3e;
  background: #3e3e3e;
  height: 75px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 7px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.main-block__line span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: -8px;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 15px;
  color: #ffffff;
  height: 25px;
  margin: 8px 0px 0px 0px;
  z-index: 2;
}

@keyframes line {
  0% {
    top: 50%;
  }

  50% {
    top: 65%;
  }

  100% {
    top: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main-block__scroll">
  <div class="main-block__image"></div>
  <div class="main-block__line"><span>scroll</span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь перемещать объект на относительную высоту в процентах. Так как контейнер имеет высоту 100vh (высота экрана), то при изменении высоты этого экрана, Вы также заставляете меняться высоту (через свойство `top`), на которую нужно переместить объект.

Ваша линия имеет высоту 75px, позиция линии = 50% от высоты контейнера, размер объекта = 24px. Соответственно, необходимо переместить объект на 50% + 75px + 24px и вернуть обратно. Делается это через функцию calc: `top: calc(50% + 75px + 24px)`.

```css
.main-block__scroll {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #161616;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.main-block__image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 24px;
  width: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  z-index: 2;
  animation: line 4s linear infinite alternate;
}

.main-block__line {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid #3e3e3e;
  background: #3e3e3e;
  height: 75px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 7px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.main-block__line span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: -8px;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 15px;
  color: #ffffff;
  height: 25px;
  margin: 8px 0px 0px 0px;
  z-index: 2;
}

@keyframes line {
  0% {
    top: 50%;
  }
  50% {
    top: calc(50% + 75px - 24px);
  }
  100% {
    top: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main-block__scroll">
  <div class="main-block__image"></div>
  <div class="main-block__line"><span>scroll</span></div>
</div>
```